# How do I implement a Shopping Cart with Empty, Update Quantity, and Submit buttons?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a page that displays the contents of a shopping cart in a table. The **Quantity** field is an editable text box, allowing the user to update its value. I need **three buttons** - one for **Empty cart**, one for **Update cart**, and one for **Submit cart**.

My ShoppingCartController has these methods:

- `postCartItem($id)`
- `putUpdateCart()`
- `deleteCartItem($id)`
- `deleteCart`

The submit button takes it to the store method of the `OrderController` resource controller

I'm going out of my mind how to do this RESTfully.

Any tips/best practices would really be appreciated.

Comment: There are cart implementations that you may either use or get ideas from, start by checking at https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/tree/master/src/Gloudemans/Shoppingcart

Comment: Okay, to clarify, the table is contained inside `form` tags, with the quantity column being `input` form elements and hence the data that will be submitted.  The form action can only be a single url.  How do I handle the behaviours of clear, update AND submit to a single url when there are multiple HTTP verbs (delete, put, post) involved?

Comment: Are you looking for how to use a resource? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers